# how to prioritize udev-rules over the driver/kernel (network interfaces names)?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, udev

I have an **ubuntu server 14.04** virtual machine  with 2 network interfaces

- `eth0` - for web management, SSH
- `eth1` - for incoming span network analysis

I've configured the machine with udev rules (to ensure consistency and proper binding of mac-addresses to logical network interfaces names.

- I'm doing it only once when installing the server
- writing these rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:f5:aa:02", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth1"
  SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:f5:aa:f8", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth0"
  ```

[image]

---

This setup works as expected **until new network interfaces are added to the machine**.
It's important to remind that the new interfaces are **not added to the udev rules**. (because I'm only doing it's once in the setup process)

I'm expecting the new network interfaces names to be any generic name (such as `eth3`/`p2p1`/`em1`/...) **as long as the name is not occupied** by a udev rule.

> This is what I experience after adding the interfaces and booting up the machine:
>
> [image]
>
> 1. my udev rule was ignored/conflicted and named `rename3`
> 2. `eth0` got hijacked. one of the new interfaces is now `eth0`. this is super-problematic security-wise (can lead to data-leakage)

This is the related flow I've found in `/var/log/messages`

```
systemd-udevd[126]: starting version 204

...

vmxnet3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
vmxnet3 0000:0b:00.0 eth1: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
vmxnet3 0000:13:00.0 eth2: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps
vmxnet3 0000:1b:00.0 eth3: NIC Link is Up 10000 Mbps

...

vmxnet3 0000:0b:00.0 rename3: renamed from eth1
vmxnet3 0000:13:00.0 eth1: renamed from eth2
systemd-udevd[396]: renamed network interface eth1 to rename3
systemd-udevd[405]: renamed network interface eth2 to eth1
```

- IMO It's a race-condition. The driver/kernel occupy the names. later when my udev rules execute, the occupied names fallback to `rename*`

---

## Question,

Is there a way to change the order and prioritize udev-rules before the driver/kernel occupy the name of the interface?

NOTE - these workarounds (POC-level) worked for me:

> - using a different naming convention in udev rules ( e.g. `management0` and `span0`) - worked without problems since it's not colliding with default.
> - script to run @ boot - will redefine the udev rules on hardware changes - worked, but requires an additional reboot (naive approach) -
>     worked without problems

Comment: "Is there a way to change the order and prioritize udev-rules before the driver/kernel occupy the name of the interface?"

No.